# SQL - progmatically change refresh rate for ALL publishers in replication monitor

Tags: sql-server-2008, monitoring, replication

How can I change progmattically change the refresh rate of all the publishers in the repliation monitor ? Without going into each one to change it's publisher setttings.

MS SQL SMS 2008 R2

AHIA, denaem